# Device model in strings.xml?

Tags: android, string, device-name

**Hello guys!**

I have got a problem, I want to make my app display the device name (if your [DEVICENAME] is rooted or not) in the strings.xml, I have already tried many things, but nothing really worked.

Please tell me how to do that! It should work in Toasts made with MainActivity.java.

Comment: Why does it need to be in strings.xml?

Comment: @PeterChappy Because I need localization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your strings.xml,

```
<string name="device">if %s is rooted or not.</string>
```

And in your Activity

```
getString(R.id.device, android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + android.os.Build.PRODUCT);
```

Comment: `PRODUCT` will give "The name of the overall product."

Comment: @user4970174  Have fun coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follow.

In your `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="device_rooted">if your %s is rooted or not</string>
```

And in Java:

```
context.getString(R.string.device_rooted, android.os.Build.MODEL);
```

Comment: `MODEL` will give "The end-user-visible name for the end product."

Comment: It's up to you to decide what you want to display. This is just an example to show how to do what you asked.

Comment: I was just adding clarification of the differences between yours and siris_cac's answers